# The setFilesToUpload action is not working for me

Tags: javascript, testing, file-upload, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm trying to upload a file to the web application I'm testing. The only Html I can identify the upload with is the class which is 'file-input'.

Currently what I have done is this, in my page-model file I have:
`this.importSection = Selector('.file-input');`

And in my test file I have:
`.setFilesToUpload(page.importSection, './my-file.xlsx')`

I have also tried directly calling the element within my test file as below:
`.setFilesToUpload('.file-input', './my-file.xlsx')`
`.setFilesToUpload(Selector('.file-input'), './my-file.xlsx')`

When running either of these I am getting the following error:
"The specified selector does not match a file input element."

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, I've searched on the testcafe & not sure what to do next.

Comment: Have you tried the `input[type="upload"]` selector? What outputs the `$$('input[type="upload"]')` expression in Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: I have the following: `<input _ngcontent-c45="" formcontrolname="importFile" hidden="" multiple="false" type="file" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">`

Answer (score 2):

This works:
Within the page-model file I have:
`this.importSection = Selector('input');`
Then within my test file `.setFilesToUpload(page.importSection.withAttribute('type', 'file'), './fileName')`

Comment: You can see a detailed [description](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/basics/test-file-upload.html) of how to test file upload in TestCafe and inspect a runnable example [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/upload-files).